# How to write tests for async actions in a project that uses redux-promise and axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, axios, redux-promise

My team recently started working on a project that uses [redux-promise](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise). The payload in each action is an axios call, like this:

```
function fetchUsers() {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_USERS,
        payload: axios.post('users')
    }
}
```

Redux-promise takes care of dispatching "a copy of the action with the resolved value of the promise" (their words). The reducer expects the data, not a promise:

```
function userReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.FETCH_USERS:
            return action.payload.data
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

The application works as intended, but writing tests has been a challenge. What's are the best practices for writing tests in this environment? I'd like to write tests for the action creator and for the reducer.

Answer (score -1):

Redux tests has a [very nice tutorial here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md) under 'Async Action Creators'

Basically all you need to do is

1. Use a library like `nock` to mock the server response
2. Use the built in `redux-mock-store` to test the redux state after calling the actions

Comment: I've looked at this tutorial, but it doesn't seem to apply to redux-promise. There are 3 actions for each operation: fetchTodosRequest, fetchTodosSuccess, and fetchTodosFailure. Redux-promise takes care of dispatching "a copy of the action with the resolved value of the promise".

Also, nock doesn't seem to play well with axios, as documented [here](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/305).